# Filter for many option

Tags: php

I have Input Variable :

```
$var_in="PDF Is from Adobe Acrobat";
```

i will strsub() 3 first and only get "PDF"

```
$key_is=substr($var_in,0,3);
```

I have some Main option, if found from $key_is

1.Option one with items :

```
"PDF", "XML", "XLS", "DOC"
```

will run somefunction1()

2.Option Two

```
"PNG", "BMP", "JPG"
```

run somefunction2()

3.Option Three

```
"DAT", "BAC", "SQL"
```

run somefunction3()

old ways is using

```
switch ($key_is) {
    case "PDF":
        runfunction1();
    break;
    case "DAT":
        runfunction3();
    break;
...
}
```

how can make it simple (Maybe some function)? 
if i add new items from main option is automatic goes to
suitable Function option selection.

like this, if i add "GIF" from main Option

```
"PNG", "BMP", "JPG", "GIF"
```

will run runfunction1()
without i need change the switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using switch and in_array()

```
//set $test_type and start a switch

    switch($test_type) {
        case in_array($test_type, $array_opt1):{
            somefunction1();
            break;
        }
        case in_array($test_type, $array_opt2):{
            somefunction2();
            break;
        }
        case in_array($test_type, $array_opt3):{
            somefunction3();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            someOtherfunction();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set $test_type ="your_type_name", and get actions according to type as below

```
 $test_type= "PDF";

        $array_opt1 = array("PDF", "XML", "XLS", "DOC");
        $array_opt2 = array("PNG", "BMP", "JPG");
        $array_opt3 = array("DAT", "BAC", "SQL");

        if(in_array($test_type, $array_opt1)){
         //send to relevant funcion for this group  
         somefunction1();
        }
        else if (in_array($test_type, $array_opt2)) {
           somefunction2();
        }else if(in_array($test_type, $array_opt3)){
           somefunction3();
        }else{
            someOtherfunction();
        }
```

Comment: Best, but if have many option, Will use many "if" . Can i use switch / case for change the "if" ?

Comment: in_array function Is new for me, it's greats function

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting each option category to a category array. So you can have

```
$imageCategories = ['images', 'PNG','BMP','GIF'];
$dataCategories = ['data','PDF','XML','XLS'];
```

then pass an array to the function called for example

```
handleCategory($categoryArray)
```

and then check just first index of array to decide which function you should run

```
switch($categoryArray[0]) {
case 'images': 
   runFunction1();
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could build your arrays smart

```
$key_is = "PDF"

$array_opt1 = array("PDF", "XML", "XLS", "DOC");
$array_opt2 = array("PNG", "BMP", "JPG");
$array_opt3 = array("DAT", "BAC", "SQL");
$array_options = array('1'=> $array_opt1, '2'=> $array_opt2,'3'=> $array_opt3);

$array_func = array('1'=> 'funct1', '2'=> 'func2','3'=> 'func3');

foreach ($array_options as $key => $array_opt){
   if (in_array($key_is, $array_opt)){
       call_user_func($array_func[$key], $param); 
   }
}
```

$array_func[$key] will give you the name of the function to use.
[call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) will call the function. You can also pas a parameter if you need. If no parameter is needed leave the $param out.

EDIT: 
If the name of the functions are unique for each option you could even use the function name as key:

```
$array_options = array('funct1'=> $array_opt1, 'funct2'=> $array_opt2,'funct3'=> $array_opt3);

foreach ($array_options as $func_name => $array_opt){
   if (in_array($key_is, $array_opt)){
       call_user_func($func_name, $param); 
   }
}
```